# Xamarin.Forms BindableProperty binding not firing in some cases

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.forms

Code sample, that show some strange issue with BindableProperty.
Code is located in GitHub
https://github.com/jonilviv/BindableProperty-issue.git
This is a Xamarin.Forms solution with 3 projects:

- Common .NET Standard project
- Android project
- iOS project
- UWP project

In common project is user-control `CustomTextView`, based on `ContentView`. This control have BindableProperty Text. Main window have 3 custom controls. And there is a strange behavior:

1. Label Text property binded to ViewModel property `TextValue`.
2. We change Text property in CS code - all is OK.
3. **We bind `Text` property to ViewModel property `TextValue`. And there is a problem: when `TextValue` changed - `Text` property not changed.**
4. We set static text to property `Text` and all is OK.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifyable example for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Problem is very and very complex: few projects in visual multi-control solution. Minimal possible code is on GitHub https://github.com/jonilviv/BindableProperty-issue

Comment: Withou a MCVE we can not help you debugging. We are not going to read through a whole project worth of code to help you. At the very least you should show us the code of the property setter that is not proper firing the Change Notificaiton + any called functions. Also all place where you assign values to the Property/it's backing field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>There is 2 solutions I think:</s>

1. Set label text directly in propertychanged event
2. Change binding to something like this `Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference controlName}}"` and set your control name. I think you should get error at this moment this current binding. Or am I wrong?

Reviewed code of viewmodel. It is incorrect.  TextValue property should be simple property, not BindableProperty. You need implement INotifyPropertyChanged in viewmodel, so it raises change to update view. Read about it [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/)

==UPDATED==

Having BindableObject as ViewModel is a bit strange. You get a lot of methods which are not needed.

Launched your code and got binding errors:

- [0:] Binding: 'TextValue' property not found on 'App2.CustomTextView', target property: 'App2.CustomTextView.Text'
- [0:] Binding: 'TextValue' property not found on 'App2.CustomTextView', target property: 'App2.CustomTextView.Text'

I think BindingDataContext is not set to that element correctly, so it does not update text. Set name form MainPage like x:Name="Page" and bind like this

- Text="{Binding BindingContext.TextValue, Source={x:Reference Page}}"

Comment: Unfortunately 1 and 2 are not possible, because we don't have event. The main problem is in that, that this even not raised. ViewModel is correct, because BindableObject have basic realization in background. Also I started from basic implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged `.

Comment: Updated my answer, check UPDATED :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works for me. Also I created separate branch, where viewModel implemented basically.